# Android How to get Audio File duration

Tags: java, android, audio, duration, pcm

i made application which use class AudioRecorder to recording files in format pcm. I made list with all files in my app and i want get duration from all files but i have problem. I tried:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
   metaRetriever.setDataSource(filePath);
```

and

```
MediaPlayer mplayer =  new MediaPlayer();
mplayer.reset();
mplayer.setDataSource(URL);
mplayer.prepare();
Integer totalFileDuration = mplayer.getDuration();
```

I have only errors with this solutions.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android dev docs:

> There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed
>   MediaPlayer object and the MediaPlayer object after reset() is called.
>   It is a programming error to invoke methods such as
>   getCurrentPosition(), getDuration(), getVideoHeight(),
>   getVideoWidth(), setAudioStreamType(int), setLooping(boolean),
>   setVolume(float, float), pause(), start(), stop(), seekTo(int),
>   prepare() or prepareAsync() in the Idle state for both cases. If any
>   of these methods is called right after a MediaPlayer object is
>   constructed, the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() won't be called by the internal player
>   engine and the object state remains unchanged; but if these methods
>   are called right after reset(), the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() will be invoked by the internal player
>   engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.

Since you're using a URL for the data source, I would try `prepareAsync()` and then call `getDuration()` in `onPrepared()`.